# Jax Ws with PHP client that always send Null parm

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I created a JaxWs service. User is trying to call it with PHP client, the only parm is a string. When I use Eclipse Web service browser (tester) it was fine. When the user tries with PHP I recieve a null parm in the method. I haven't done any customizing to wsdl or code. Thanks in advance for any pointers...

Method

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "my.endpoint.class")
    public class ExternalReportsImpl implements ExternalReports {
private org.w3c.dom.Document doc;
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
private enum Types {
    tfbData, tfbRate, tfbSupport, tfbMakes, tfbVin, tfbSave, tfbRetrieve;
}
@Override

public String getReports(String xmlSource){
    XmlHelper xh;
    SupportTables support =  new SupportTables();
    Connection con = null;  
    Policy policy  = null;
    String schema  = "";
    String ret     = "";
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)   context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
    try {
        xh = new XmlHelper();
        doc = xh.loadDoc(xmlSource);
             }
```

WSDL Snippet

```
<message name="getReports"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getReports"/></message><message name="getReportsResponse"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getReportsResponse"/></message><portType name="ExternalReports"><operation name="getReports"><input wsam:Action="http://my.class/ExternalReports/getReportsRequest" message="tns:getReports"/><output wsam:Action="http://my.class/ExternalReports/getReportsResponse" message="tns:getReportsResponse"/></operation></portType>
```

PHP CLIENT

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $url = 'http://my.endpoint/ExternalReportsWebService?wsdl';

    $client = new SoapClient($url);

    class getReports {
  function __construct($arg0) {
    $this->getReports = $arg0;
}
    }

   class getReportsResponse {
function __construct($arg0='') {
    $this->getReportsResponse = $arg0;
}
     }

     //$GR = new getReports(file_get_contents("test/test.xml") );
     $GR = new getReports("test") );
     $GRR = new getReportsResponse();

      $report = new SoapVar( $GR  , SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'getReports', $url);
      $response = new SoapVar( $GRR  , SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'getReportsResponse', $url);

      echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(print_r($client->getReports($report, $response), true)));
```

Add this code to PHP CLIENT

```
     echo "<br> LAST REQUEST <br>"  ;
     echo $client->__getLastRequest();
     echo " <br> Functions <br>"  ;
     echo $client->__getFunctions();
     echo " <br> Types <br>"  ;
     echo $client->__getTypes();
     echo "<br> Request headers <br>"  ;
     echo $client->__getLastRequestHeaders();
```

CLIENT TRACE RESULTS

```
    LAST REQUEST
        TEST
    Functions
       Array
    Types
       Array
    Request headers
       POST /myApp/ExternalReportsWebService HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080          Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.14 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "" Content-Length: 531
```

Comment: Hm, hard to say... did you try to trace the SOAP message sent from the PHP client?

Comment: I have debugged on my Java side. I started coding PHP two days ago to try and figure this out. I tried all the examples I could find for PHP Clients nothing worked. I will research Soap tracing in PHP

Comment: @home When I set tracing on, I see the string parm that should be sent using echo $client->__getLastRequest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this link

http://www.lampjunkie.com/2010/03/get-phps-soapclient-to-speak-with-javas-jax-ws/

My schema has named params

```
 <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://my.namespace/"><xs:element name="getReports" type="tns:getReports"/><xs:element name="getReportsResponse" type="tns:getReportsResponse"/><xs:complexType name="getReports"><xs:sequence><xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="getReportsResponse"><xs:sequence><xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:schema>
```

had to add

```
$addRequest = new stdClass();
$addRequest->argO = "String I was sending";
$response = $client->add($addRequest);
```